# Drools : Rule Formation - One Rule output should trigger other Rules

Tags: jboss, drools

I am fairly new to Drools and getting my head around it.
Scenario:

rule A output -> should trigger Rule b , Rule c and send then get the final  output etc

Example : For simplification

```
CountryBean --> { String isdCode ,List<String> tates} 

rule "Get States by Country's ISD Code"
no-loop true
  when country: Country(isCode=="+1")
then 
  country.setStates("Kentucky" , "North Carolina"....);
  update(country);

StateBean --> {String state,String population}
rule "Get Population of States"
no-loop true
  when state: States(state !="", $state=state)
then 
  if(state=="Kentucky")
  state.population("1M");
  update(state)
```

**My Solution**

1. Execute the first Rule
2. then iterate over the states and execute States rules

   ```
   Country country = new Country("+1");
     ksession.insert(country )
     ksession.fireAllRules();
   List<States> stateList=new ArrayList<States>();
   country.getStates().forEach(state-> {
       ksession.insert(new State(state)); 
       ksession.fireAllRules();stateList.add(state);
   });
   ```

I dont think this is the right way to do it. How should I approach this problem ?

Comment: I cant see any issue with this approach. why you think this approach is not correct ?

Comment: Does this need to be stateful